# i want to declare an array inside a function with the size of an array in main butt getting error

Tags: c++

I want to declare an array inside a function with the size of an array in `main` but I am getting an error in the part where I am defining the `left[]` array. What can I do to get the desired output or to eliminate the error?

```
void merge_sort(int * A, const int s)
{
    const int mid = s / 2;
    int left[mid];  // getting error about mid    
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 9;    
    int arr[SIZE] = {1,2,4,5,1,2,3,3,4};

    merge_sort(arr, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: It is always helpful if you provide the error message. Secondly: are you limited to C or can you use C++?

Comment: I have no idea what that meant.

Comment: @uceumern "So can you please give me a solution? What can I do to achieve the desired result?" OP omitted some words but the question is pretty clear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry, my language parser failed, yours seems more advanced ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error: ‘s’ is not a constant expression
     int mid = s / 2;
                   ^
```

A simple solution to this problem is to make SIZE a global constexpr variable and use that to calculate the other constant expressions.

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t SIZE = 9;

void merge_sort(int* A)
{
    constexpr size_t mid = SIZE / 2;

    int left[mid];
}

int main()
{
    int arr[SIZE] = {1,2,4,5,1,2,3,3,4};
    merge_sort(arr);
}
```

Instead of using c-style arrays, consider using `std::array` from C++ which lets you use iterators and other handy C++ features. Converted, it'd look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr size_t SIZE = 9;

void merge_sort(std::array<int, SIZE>& A)
{
    constexpr size_t mid = SIZE / 2;

    std::array<int, mid> left;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, SIZE> arr = {1,2,4,5,1,2,3,3,4};
    merge_sort(arr);
    for(auto v : arr) {
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    }
}
```

The subscript operator (`operator[]`) works like on c-style arrays, so `arr[0]` would give you access to the first element in the array.

You could however take a look at the other containers, like `std::vector`, if you'd like to be able to create arrays with dynamic sizes.

Answer (score 4):

C++ (in constrast to C) does not support variable length arrays, i.e. arrays where at least one dimension is not a compile-time-constant.

```
const int mid = s / 2;
int left[mid];
```

In you program, `s` is not known at compile time, so `mid` is not known at compile time. Hence `int left[mid]` is a variable length array that is not supported by standard C++

In C++, you would probably use a (dynamic) container like `std::vector` and set the dimension in advance (instead of pushing values to it one after the other):

```
std::vector<int> left;
left.resize(s/2);

left[0] = 10;  // access it just like an "old style array"
```

Comment: afaik `std::vector<int> left(s/2);` avoids to have 2 allocations happening

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies here:

```
const int mid = s / 2;
int left[mid]; //getting error on the mid
```

s / 2 is not a constant, and can hence, not be used to make array as this needs to be a compile time constant to be standard compliant. There are some compilers which allow this, but as I said, this is not standard. MSVC gives the following error `expression did not evaluate to a constant`.

By the way, `#` is not a comment in C++.